# Host ASP.NET App In WCF or Generic Web Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, webforms

Objective:

We have a Windows Service/generic EXE that also hosts a WCF service (.Net 3.5). I'd like to be able to take a third party ASP.NET component in a DLL, and host it through that WCF Service.

Is this possible to do, in any way?

It seems like if you want to host a ASP.NET app, it must be through IIS, but we don't use IIS.
Is there any way that we could load the ASP.NET app into memory, make the app available through an endpoint, and receive requests back from the app?

Specifically, we'd like to take the "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll", expose the web form in a web page, and accept any requests back from the web form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx

Looking for anything to get me started. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

From [`owin.org`](http://owin.org/)

"`OWIN` defines a standard interface between .NET web servers and web applications. The goal of the `OWIN` interface is to decouple server and application, encourage the development of simple modules for .NET web development, and, by being an open standard, stimulate the open source ecosystem of .NET web development tools."

Essentially `Owin` implementations, like [`Katana`](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/documentation) (OWIN implementations for Microsoft servers and frameworks.), help you self host web apps, even in a Windows NT Service.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post, hosting a WebForms app outside IIS/ASP.NET is not possible.

> WebForms are tightly coupled to ASP.NET/IIS and cannot run directly on
>   OWIN/Katana (e.g. outside of ASP.NET/IIS). However, you should be able
>   to use Katana's middleware (Security, CORS, etc.) in a WebForms
>   application.

http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/571291